# PySpark - Lookup comma seperated values with dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a **PySpark** dataframe "df_data" that holds multiple numeric values separated by comma:

| Name | Preferences |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 1,3,2 |
| Tim | 2,3 |

Additionally, I have another data frame "df_lookup" that holds information on the numeric value for which I want to perform a lookup and append a column to the "df_data":

| ID | Preferences |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Politics |
| 2 | Entertainment |
| 3 | Sports |

The expected result should be like this:

| Name | Preferences |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | Politics,Sports,Entertainment |
| Tim | Entertainment,Sports |

For this purpose, I already converted the "df_lookup" into a dictionary:

```
lookup_dict = {row.asDict()["ID"] : row.asDict()["Preferences"] for row in df_lookup.collect()}
```

As a next step, I wanted to split the values from the column "Preferences" within the "df_data" dataframe:

```
df_data = df_data.withColumn("preferences_array", expr("split(preferences, ',')"))
```

To then finally perform the lookup and mapping:

```
mapped_df = df_data.select(explode("preferences_array").alias("preferences_id")) \
    .withColumn("preferences_description", variables_dict[col("preferences_id")])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'
```

Comment: The data storage here is poor. Can you alter it at the DB level?

Comment: I totally agree, but I get the data as part of an export from a cloud-based data collection service which is using a fixed schema…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code -

After creating the preferences_array, paste the below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

map_col = create_map([lit(x) for i in lookup_dict.items() for x in i])
df_data = df_data.withColumn("Preferences_Name", transform('preferences_array', lambda x: map_col[x]))
df_data = df_data.withColumn("Preferences_Name",
   concat_ws(",",col("Preferences_Name")))
```

Finally drop and rename the columns as per your need.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly fine (even though the actual storage of data is not optimal, but unfortunately, not configurable).